# Java Display message issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

I have a java program that creates a JFrame like this:

```
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            gui.setFrame(new gui(), 1000, 300);
        }
    });
```

I also have a class (gui.java) that implements setFrame:

```
  public static void setFrame(final JFrame frame, final int width, final int height) {
 SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
 public void run() {
   f1=frame;
 frame.setTitle("Testing");
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setSize(width, height);
 frame.setVisible(true);   
}
});
}
```

If the user tries to click Submit (a button I created) and the fields in the JFrame are not filled in then it throws an error. The code for the error message is:

```
     submit.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    //check to make sure all values filled in
          if(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()!=null&&saveChooser.getSelectedFile().toString()!=null)
        parseFile.readFile(chooser.getSelectedFile(),saveChooser.getSelectedFile(),startSpanText.getText(),(String)col2.getSelectedItem(),(String)col3.getSelectedItem(),(String)col4.getSelectedItem(),(String)col5.getSelectedItem(),(String)col6.getSelectedItem());     
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1,"Bad");
}
```

});

//Note: f1 is a static version of the frame I initially received

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at gui$3.mouseReleased(gui.java:133)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out which object is null in your mouseReleased function via debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the variables is null. It could be:

- chooser
- chooser.getSelectedFile()
- saveChooser
- saveChooser.getSelectedFile()
- parseFile
- startSpanText
- col2 to col6

Use the line number in the stack trace, and a debugger or traces in the code to know which one. My guess would be one of the selected files, since it makes no sense to call

```
chooser.getSelectedFile().toString() != null
```

Either there is no selected file, and it throws an NPE because `getSelectedFile()` returns null, or there is one, and its `toString()` will never be null.

Also, you shouldn't use a mouse listener to do something when a button is pressed. That's what an ActionListener is for. It will be simpler, and also work when the user presses the button with its keyboard.

Comment: Thank you both, because of your answers I realized that the variables chooser and saveChooser were not the actual files. They were instances of JFileChooser. I needed to get the text of the actual file path instead of the chooser.

Answer (score 0):

Your exception message should point you to the answer. One of the items you are using in your `mouseReleased` method is null:

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
  //check to make sure all values filled in
  if(chooser.getSelectedFile().toString()!=null && 
      saveChooser.getSelectedFile().toString()!=null)
    parseFile.readFile(chooser.getSelectedFile(), saveChooser.getSelectedFile(),
        startSpanText.getText(), (String)col2.getSelectedItem(), 
        (String)col3.getSelectedItem(), (String)col4.getSelectedItem(),
        (String)col5.getSelectedItem(), (String)col6.getSelectedItem());     
  else
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f1,"Bad");
}
```

Use a debugger to inspect which variables are set. Use the line number in the exception message to help you.

Comment: Thanks! You helped point me in the right direction. @JB Nizet answered first though.

Comment: @Rilcon42 No problem. He actually answered second, but his answer is more comprehensive.